# DLookup returns "0" instead of the right value

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have this block of code for a form with the following lines of code:

```
Private Sub Variedade_AfterUpdate()
Dim SPval As Single
Variety = Variedade.Value
SPval = DLookup("[SpSix]", "tblSP", "[NumRecipe] = '" & Variety & "'")
ValSP6Table = SPval
End Sub
```

- **tblSP** -> Table with the values.
- **SpSix** -> Field I want from tblSP.
- **NumRecipe** -> Field that is compared to Variety.

It is set to run on the field Variedade "after updating", where it gets a value from a dropdown list with values like "1481B" and "6265C". ValSP6Table is another field from the form that is supposed to get the value automatically.

When I run it, the field ValSP6Table gets a value of 0 instead of one of the values from the list, and the dropdown list has no values named "0".

I made this small codeblock from excerpts from the internet that I understood. I tried other ways of formatting but I always get a syntax error.

Comment: Is this the full code? If DLookup returns `0` and not a runtime error, it seems that tblSP.SpSix is actually `0`. You can add a `Debug.Print Variety, SPval` after the DLookup, the output goes to the Immediate window (Ctrl+G). This will help to find the problem.

Comment: In what terms VB.NET is involved in this code? Please use only relevant Tags for your problem. People attracted here by the invalid tag could react not well.

Comment: Ok @Steve, I'm sorry, first time posting and I added the wrong tag.

@Andre the debug showed the correct values

`2513C    0,5` `2517Q    0,35` `2533A    0,35`

Answer (score 0):

You haven't dimmed Variety (nor ValSP6Table):

```
Private Sub Variedade_AfterUpdate()

    Dim SPval As Single
    Dim Variety As String

    Variety = Variedade.Value
    SPval = DLookup("[SpSix]", "tblSP", "[NumRecipe] = '" & Variety & "'")
    ValSP6Table = SPval

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your control Variedade is linked to a table field in your form?

Put a

debug.print Variety

before the Dlookup Statement and look what if printed in the immediate windows (Press Ctrl-G in your code editor to view it).

Comment: I put a debug on both variables and the Immediate window showed me the correct values.
    `2513C          0,5`
    `2517Q          0,35`
    `2533A          0,35`

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that `ValSP6Table` is of type Byte, Integer or Long? All your debug outputs show 0.xxx fractional values that will be 0 if converted (casted) to an integer type.

Comment: I already added a `Debug.Print ValueSP6Table` and it showed the same value as SpSix.

Comment: Then there are two possibilities left: either your field is formatted to suppress fractions of numbers (i.e. showing only the integer part) or the assignment is somehow losing the fractions. Can you show the code where you assign the `ValueSP6Table` to your actual form field? Or, if `ValueSP6Table`is the form field, then put the whole `Sub`into the code belonging to the form and write `Me!ValueSP6Table` instead.

Comment: I put the `Sub` into the form now and used `Me` but the result is the same. I tested `SpVal` with the values `1.5` and `1`, and `ValueSP6Table` yielded a `1` result both times, so maybe you were right in saying it loses its fractions. Though in the field properties of `ValueSP6Table` I have it set as numeric with 2 decimals.

Comment: Yes, then it is definitely a Double -> Int problem. Can you put another field on the form and use this one instead of `ValueSp6Table`?

Comment: I think I can, but if I do that how do I then send the data to the form, since `ValueSP6Table` is the field in question?

Comment: So `ValueSp6Table` is a field in your form bound to a table, right? Can you please look at the data type of this field in the table?

Comment: I don't think it is bound to a table, it is a field on the form itself and the only data type I see is in the formatting tab or the data tab but the only ones there are Rich Text and Simple Text.

Comment: Then try the following: put a new field on the form and add `Me!NewField = SPval`to your code.

Answer (score -1):

I managed to solve my own question with your help. My `ValueSP6Table` field didn't work with decimal numbers so I turned all of them into `Integers` (e.g. `0,35` -> `35`) and changed the form's field formatting to this `="0," & [ValueSP6Table].[Value]`. Not the cleanest way to do it, but it works.

Thanks for all your help.